# python добавить в вывод один общий <table>

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, django, flask

Каждая новая строка обрамляется тегом `table` нужно что бы тег `table` был на все строки, а не на каждую отдельно, как сделать? Хочу что бы была полноценная таблица, а не много маленьких табличек.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#! /usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi, os
import time
import datetime as dt
import datetime

print ("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print ("<H1>DGFDGFDG</H1>")

now = dt.datetime.now()
now1 = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
ago = now - dt.timedelta(minutes=10)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("R:\nation"):
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)
        mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        mtime1 = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(st.st_mtime))
        if mtime < ago:

            some_string = '''
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>{0}</td>
            <td>{1}</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            '''.format(path[26:38],mtime1)

            print(some_string)
```

вывод:

```
   <table>
    <tr>
    <td>6C3B6B42C5BE</td>
    <td>09.06.2020 16:09:12</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>6C3B6B42C5BE</td>
    <td>09.06.2020 16:09:12</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Должно быть:

```
   <table>
    <tr>
    <td>6C3B6B42C5BE</td>
    <td>09.06.2020 16:09:12</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>6C3B6B42C5BE</td>
    <td>09.06.2020 16:09:12</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: печатайте `<table>` и `</table>` до и после цикла соответственно

Comment: @splash58 ееее наконец то получилось) спасибо